# Azure AD GET TenantDetails

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I've been playing with some code that queries the current user's tenant details.

However I noticed that when I sign-in using a normal non-admin user the countryLetterCode is returned as null. 
If I sign-in using an admin user the value is returned.

If I do the same steps through the graph explorer graphexplorer.cloudapp.net the countryLetterCode is returned in both cases - for both admin and non-admin users.

Any ideas

Thanks

Donal

Answer (score 1):

I am using the Azure Graph client(C#) to acquire the **countryLetterCode**, it works for both normal user and Admin. Here is the code for your reference:

```
string graphResourceId = "https://graph.windows.net";

Uri servicePointUri = new Uri(graphResourceId);
Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(servicePointUri, tenantId);

ActiveDirectoryClient client = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot, async () => await Task.FromResult(accessToken));

Console.WriteLine(client.TenantDetails.ExecuteAsync().Result.CurrentPage.First().CountryLetterCode);
```

Which language were you developing? Would you mind share the code you were developing?

And since the Azure Graph REST could works well, I also suggest that you use the REST API as a workaround.

### Update

Based on the test, if I remove the permission `Directory.Read.All` on the portal, then the normal user can't get the **countryLetterCode** as you described. Please check this permission on the portal to see whether it is helpful.

Comment: Hi @Fei Xue - MSFT,

Comment: Hi @Fei Xue - MSFT, are you running you code as a web app or native app. Also what permissions have you given your app and are they admin consented.

Comment: @DonalMcWeeney I am developing with native app, but this issue should not be relative to the type of app since we can call the Azure Graph REST directly. I am update the orignal post, please check whether it is helpful.

Comment: I also found the following link [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2015/03/18/update-to-graph-api-consent-permissions/) where they changed the behaviour to now treat web and native apps differently as regards the directory read permission! Thanks...

Comment: There seems be some misunderstanding. Which I means the app type doesn't affect the behavior you described is that the REST request only require the token. No matter the token issued for the web app or the native app, it will not affect the REST response. The possible reason to impact the result is the claim in the token like scope/roles and the user type(normal or admin). The link you provided described the different consent behavior to acquire the token. Was the issue fixed after you check `Directory.Read.All`?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the non-admin user can call TenantDetails and get just the basic of info back...

From the permissions reference for User.Read/"Sign-in and read user profile" - "Also allows the app to read the following basic company information of the signed-in user (through the TenantDetail object): tenant ID, tenant display name, and verified domains."

However still does not explain why the graph explorer can read it.